# How do I display a custom annotation on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to add a custom annotation to my map view. My goal is to have it so when you tap the annotation, there will be a picture, a label for a name, and a label for how far away the annotation is from your location (I can add the calculation logic later). I've googled for a long time and all the answers are very confusing. Would I need a custom MKAnnotation, a custom MKAnnotationView, or both? Also, what delegate methods, etc. Thanks!x

Comment: Hey Minebomber, Try this link step-wise https://bakyelli.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation-protocol/                                                         and you will get the output...

Answer (score 0):

Refer this url link you can add custom annotations on MapView.

https://bakyelli.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation-protocol/